# AWK or Sed, or together?

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk

I think i have a sed or awk question. I am trying to manipulate a config file from a bash script, but i can't find the right way to do it.

I have the following in my config file:

```
bla.update(
{'test': {'tag': 'twenty',
```

and want to replace it to:

```
bla.update({
'test': {'tag': 'twenty',
```

I tried all sort of sed & awk tutorials, but i can't find it.

It must be not too hard i guess, but i am stuck, please help me!!

Comment: is the general pattern just to move the open brace to the previous line?

Comment: Yes, that is the only thing indeed ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/(\n{/({\n/g'`

works for me

Answer (score 2):

With GNU awk so you can read the whole file at one time using `-v RS='\0'` (will also work with SOME other awks):

```
$ awk -v RS='\0' -v ORS= '{gsub(/\n{/,"{\n")}1' file
bla.update({
'test': {'tag': 'twenty',
```

With other awks you can use some other character that's not present in the input file, e.g. a control-C or similar, instead of `\0` as the Record Separator above or you can do:

```
$ awk -v RS= -v ORS='\n\n' '{gsub(/\n{/,"{\n")}1' file
bla.update({
'test': {'tag': 'twenty',
```

but it will compress sequences of consecutive blank lines to a single blank line and add a trailing blank line at the end of the file if one wasn't already present.

Finally, you can construct a string from the whole file contents read one line at a time using any awk and then operate on that string in the END section:

```
$ awk '{s=s $0 ORS} END{gsub(/\n{/,"{\n",s); printf "%s",s}' file
bla.update({
'test': {'tag': 'twenty',
```

Answer (score 1):

Some like this:

```
awk 'f {sub(/{/,x);f=0} /bla.update/ {$0=$0 "{";f=1}1'
bla.update({
'test': {'tag': 'twenty',
```

It search for `bla.update` and then add `{` at the end and set flag `f=1`
If flag `f` is set then remove `{` from start of line and clear flag.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an attempt using `sed`

```
sed 'N;s/(\s*\n\s*{/({\n/g' file
```

Sample Input:

```
bla.update(
{'test': {'tag': 'twenty',
```

Output:

```
bla.update({
'test': {'tag': 'twenty',
```